# Texto no se muestra por consola en inyección dll

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, hook

tengo un problema con la consola que se crea al insertar un dll en un juego de Unity. Esta imprime el primer print pero ninguno más.

Este seria el *dllmain.cpp*:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Minhook.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include "hooks.h"

void init() {
    // Crea consola
    AllocConsole();
    FILE* f;
    freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

    // Inicialización de Minhook
    MH_Initialize(); }

void main() {
    init();
    printf("Speed Changer by meganano202\n");
    changespeed(); }

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)main,0,0,0);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE; }
```

Y este *hooks.h*:

```
#pragma once
#include "offsets.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void(__fastcall* set_FortunaSpeed_Orig)(DWORD*, float, const DWORD*);
void __fastcall set_FortunaSpeed_Hook(DWORD* __this, float value, const DWORD* method)
{
    float newSpeed = value * 0.25f; // Modifica el factor multiplicador según tus necesidades
    printf("FortunaSpeed replaced with hook. New value: %f\n", newSpeed);
    // Modifica el valor de _fortunaSpeed directamente en la instancia
    *(float*)((uintptr_t)__this + 0x36C) = newSpeed;
    set_FortunaSpeed_Orig(__this, newSpeed, method);
}

void changespeed() {
    MH_CreateHook(reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(gameAssembly + set_FortunaSpeed), &set_FortunaSpeed_Hook, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&set_FortunaSpeed_Orig));
    MH_EnableHook(reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(gameAssembly + set_FortunaSpeed));
}
```

Por si les hace falta tambien muestro *offsets.h*:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

uintptr_t gameAssembly = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandleA("GameAssembly.dll");
uintptr_t set_FortunaSpeed = 0x2D59B0; //La direccion debe de estar en hexadecimal
```

Por consola sale *Speed Changer by meganano202* pero no sale *FortunaSpeed replaced with hook. New value:* y tampoco veo cambios en la velocidad

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he podido arreglar usando `FreeConsole` en vez de `AllocConsole`

Comment: Pero `FreeConsole` elimina la consola. ¿Cómo hiciste para solucionarlo? Por favor mejora tu respuesta para que le pueda servir a más personas.